Bash script that takes multiple path arguments and checks if files can be successfully created there
I would like a bash shell script (for my Debian 12 system) which accepts multiple paths as arguments, and then checks if a file can be successfully created in each one. Then the result should be put into json format.
The command to run should be:
./checkavailable.sh /the/first/path /the/second/path

(where there could be any number of input paths given, but at least one)
and I would like the output to be in the following format:
[
  { "is_available": 0, "path": "/the/first/path/" },
  { "is_available": 1, "path": "/the/second/path/" }
]

Currently, I managed to achieve this with the following script:
#!/bin/bash

# Check if first path is available
if touch $1/checkalivefile ; then
    avail_path1=1
    rm $1/checkalivefile
else
    avail_path1=0
fi

# Check if second path is available
if touch $2/checkalivefile ; then
    avail_path2=1
    $2/checkalivefile
else
    avail_path2=0
fi

echo "["
printf "  { \"is_available\": "$avail_path1", \"path\": \"$1\" } "
printf ",\n"
printf "  { \"is_available\": "$avail_path2", \"path\": \"$2\" } "
echo
echo "]"


but it's obviously a bit primitive and is hardcoded to work with x2 arguments only, and doesn't scale to additional arguments.
I could try to add a loop now. However, I came across this script, which seems to do something similar (to get disk usage in this case) but using awk instead of a loop:
#!/bin/bash

echo "["
du -s -B1 "$@" | awk '{if (NR!=1) {printf ",\n"};printf "  { \"dir_size_bytes\": "$1", \"path\": \""$2"\" }";}'
echo
echo "]"

Can someone show how this approach using "awk" could be used in my case? I am very new to bash scripts, so hope to learn something.
----EDIT----
For context, the reason for generating the json output in this particular format, is because it can be interpreted directly by the input plugins in Telegraf, which can convert it automatically into fields and tags metrics for sending to a database.

what should be result for ./checkavailable.sh /dir/file1 /dir/file1 ?

@jhnc If you mean when input arguments are just duplicated? Then it's fine to duplicate the output (I don't expect this to ever arise though).

@jhnc [
{ "is_available": 1, "path": "/dir/file1" },
{ "is_available": 1, "path": "/dir/file1" }
]

I would expect at least one to be not available. Once the path has been "used" by the consumer the first time, it would no longer be available for the next time. Perhaps it would be better to deduplicate input paths, so that only a single record is output in such cases

@teeeeee Your latest edit introduced rm $1/checkalivefile. Then, why do you touch the file in the first place? You can simply test its presence with -e, the writeability of its parent with -w etc.

@pmf The intention was to be absolutely sure that I am able to create a new file in particular directories (to check certain drives are still mounted, etc). If I permanently keep a "checkalivefile" in each directory, then I've notices sometimes that it can still appear available (e.g. using ls) even after a drive is abruptly disconnected. So, I wanted to make certain by creating a brand new file instead (and then removing it if successful)

@teeeeee But touch won't complain if the file is already there...

@pmf Yeah it could be okay. Again, it was just to be sure for my own peace of mind that there was nothing in the folder before the check, then a brand new file was able to be created.

A basic concept in programming: If you have to apply an operation to a collection of items, you iterate over them. In most programming languages, you have two basic tools for iteration: Loop and recursive functions. In bash, you will find the use of a recursive function not very convenient (try it, if you want to practice!), so a loop is the obvious approach to your problem. The useful command built into bash for loops is for, but in other situations you will perhaps find the external commands xargs or find convenient for looping operation.

BTW, the approach you tried does use a loop; you are just using awk for looping. However, I would find the use of awk pretty unnatural in your case, and perhaps lead to awkward code.  For instance, your awk program assumes that the pathnames don't contain white space characters, a somewhat unrealistic assumption.

It is cross posted from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/782873/bash-script-that-takes-multiple-path-arguments-and-checks-if-files-can-be-succes

@pmf I understand that touch them removing with rm is cumbersome and unnecessary if "touch wont complain if the file is already there". But what's the benefit of using "test" over "touch" on its own then?

@teeeeee Tell us under which circumstances (file exists, is writeable, parents exist, are writeable, etc) you want is_available to carry 0 or 1 (fyi: JSON also has booleans). If that is exhaustively defined, we can tell you what which test can do for you. Currently touch will fail if it could not update that path's access and modification times, regardless of the file being present or not. Depending on your actual goals, also consider using touch -c.

@pmf I have NFS shares mounted in various directories. I want a way to check if the connection was lost. So I want to be able to check that new files can be successfully written to these directories where the mounts are supposed to appear. So I believe I don't care about parent dirs, or if any files exist (I was only creating a dummy file before as a check that the directory was present and writable). Does it make sense?

@pmf I'm not sure I understand how/when/touch will fail. Apologies, but can you elaborate?

@jhnc I see what you mean, you're right. My question was perhaps a bit misleading then in that sense. I'm not trying to check whether a file with a particular name can be created (you're right that if it already exists then technically it wouldn't be "available". ). I'm actually trying to test whether the path is available for writing any new files to it

@pmf I am trying to use test instead of touch, but the behaviour doesn't look correct. After the drive is disconnected, "test -w" still returns "true" on the directory: myuser@mymachine:~$ echo $(test -w /path/to/dir) $? 1  However... "touch" fails, as it should:   myuser@mymachine:~$ touch /path/to/dir/checkalive.txt touch: cannot touch '/path/to/dir/checkalive.txt': Input/output error   Could it be because the directory hangs around afterwards? This is one of the reasons I was inclined to use touch/rm in the first place.

Please don't multipost - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/782873/bash-script-that-takes-multiple-path-arguments-and-checks-if-files-can-be-succes.

@teeeeee Re "I have NFS shares mounted […] I was only creating a dummy file before as a check that the directory was present and writable": You can simply test using [ -d "$path" ] (succeeds if the path (where you wanted to create the dummy file in) exists and is a directory) and [ -w "$path" ] (succeeds if that path (a directory by the first check) is writeable). But that will not tell you if something is mounted there (the mountpoint without a mount probably still is a writeable directory). Rather use the mount, df, or (especially for NFS mounts) showmount commands to check that.

Note that touch can take multiple arguments, so touch "$@" would already perform that command on all paths provided to your script. Depending on what is_available actually stands for in your desired output, you could then just query if the files are actually present, are writeable, etc.
Here's an approach that still iterates over your script's arguments using a for loop, applies touch individually, and checks its (negated) exit code $?. These are then fed into a simple jq script that takes care of returning a valid JSON encoding, regardless of any strange characters in the paths provided.
#!/bin/sh

for path; do ! touch "$path/dummy"; echo $?; rm -f "$path/dummy"; done |
jq -n --args '[$ARGS.positional[] | {is_available: input, path: .}]' "$@"

Note: Swallow stderr by using touch … 2>/dev/null to silence the error messages printed on failure.


I have NFS shares mounted in various directories. I want a way to check if the connection was lost. So I want to be able to check that new files can be successfully written to these directories where the mounts are supposed to appear. […] I was only creating a dummy file before as a check that the directory was present and writable.

I'm afraid, touch won't help you in that case, (and neither would a test with -d and -w), as they won't tell you if something is mounted there or not. After all, an unmounted mountpoint may very well still be a writeable directory. Thus, rather use the df command which lists actual mountpoints, narrow down by file system e.g. using -t nfs4, and proceed as before.
#!/bin/sh

for path; do ! df -t nfs4 "$path" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; echo $?; done |
jq -n --args '[$ARGS.positional[] | {is_available: input, path: .}]' "$@"



Thanks, but I receive an error "jq: command not found". [… I] don't want to install new package

There's no need to install any new packages: you can simply download and execute the binary directly. Also, keep in mind that with arbitrary input strings (which in this case is the path names which could contain almost any character), you'll have a hard time trying to properly encode them for a hand-crafted JSON output. Therefore, I strongly discourage anyone from using the following alternative in production, but for an approach that simply dumps the strings into quotes, no matter what, risking an invalid JSON output, replace (in any of the above scripts) the jq line with:
while read -r is_av; do
  printf '{"is_available": %d, "path": "%s"}\n,' "$is_av" "$1"; shift
done | sed '1s/^/[/;$s/,/]/'


Thanks, but I receive an error "jq: command not found". Can you provide an example like the one in the OP (which uses awk), so that it works on minimal Debian without installing additional packages?

jq is a standard tool (see the link above), which should be available in your Debian repos. While I strongly discourage you from trying to manually JSON-encode arbitrary input strings, here's one (fragile!) way employing awk: for path; do ! touch "$path/checkalivefile"; printf '{"is_available": "%d", "path": "%s"}\n' $? "$path"; done | awk 'BEGIN {print "["} NR>1 {print ","} {print} END {print "]"}'. Do not use this in production.

Thanks. I am running the script inside a pre-compiled docker container, so don't want to install new package. In the question, I also remove the file after successful creation (using rm). Can you modify the awk verison to include that?

Re "don't want to install new package": There's no need to install, you can simply download and execute the binary. Re "I also remove the file":See my comment above and/or just insert rm "$path/checkalivefile" after echo $? (use the -f flag to silence a file not found error).

I know lq is a powerful JSON tool, but requiring jq for this seem overkill, as we just have 1 (quite simple) formatted string to apply.

@F.Hauri Au contraire! As soon as you have to deal with arbitrary input data (which in this case is the path names which can contain almost any character), you better employ a reliable JSON encoder than reinventing the weel yourself by trying to manually prepare for every possibility. Yet, it doesn't need to be jq, any proven JSON processor would probably do.

It's decidedly weird to want JSON output but not want to install the de facto standard tool for processing JSON.

The use of touch and rm to write and then remove a file is cumbersome. The shell already provides an option for this.
for path; do
    test -w "$path" && echo "$path"
done

The requirement to output JSON is weird. Unix tools should probably produce text by default, though having an option to produce JSON is always nice.
printf '%s' "["
sep=""
for path; do
    test -w "$path"
    printf '%s{"is_available": %d, "path": "%s"}' "$sep" $((1 - $?)) "${path//[\\\"]/\\&}"
    sep=","
done
printf '%s' "]"

The expression ${path//[\\\"]/\\&} requires Bash. This parameter expansion will backslash-escape any literal backslash or double quote.
If you specifically want to test whether a file named checkalivefile can be created in each of the paths you pass in, it's not hard to change the script to do that; but to me, it makes more sense to pass in the thing that you actually want to test (and so you would pass in /the/first/path/checkalivefile and /the/second/path/checkalivefile if those are what you want to check for).

This will not give same answer files are pointed instead of a directories! In other word: Will match writable files too.

It's not clear whether the OP is passing in directories or files. By their expected output, it looks like those paths are actually directories; but in keeping with Unix principles, this simply passes back the input as output. If you want to know whether / is writable, you can check that. If you want to know whether you can create /foo, you can check that.

Question's title say checks if files can be successfully created there. Then it shouldn't be files, fifos or devices!

I'm really not sure. Can files be created in /? If you have the permissions, you can create /foo.

I'm really sure file can't be created on files! You have to use test -d and test -w! ( Something like test -d "$path" && test -w "$path"; echo $((1-$?)) ;-)

And for avoiding issue whenever $?  become higher than 1, you could use $(( $? ? 0 : 1 ))

If /foo exists but you have permissions to overwrite, the script will tell you this.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Hi both,  I have NFS shares mounted in various directories on the system, and want a way to check if the connection was lost. So I want to be able to check that new files can be successfully written to these directories where the mounts are supposed to appear. I don't need to ever check files directly (I was only creating a dummy file before as a check that the directory was present and writable). The inputs should only ever be paths to directories, and I am not concerned about protecting against files being passed as inputs.

When using test -w path, is there some potential issue because return 1 is false and return 0 is true in bash?

The arithmetic evaluation $((1-$?)) addresses that. If $? is 0, the result is 1, and vice versa.

@tripleee I see. good. Mine has colon character (:) between "path" and the path name. Yours has comma. (Although comma is used between the "isavailable" and "path" fields. Can you fix this? Also, can you add the new line between each directory, for printing readability, like in the OP?

@tripleee Additionally, I want to use the touch/rm approach, because using test -w does not give a faithful result when the directory is an NFS mount. However, touch still is representative of whether the mounted drive is usable (it will fail either with an Input/Output error, or it will hang. The latter can be detected with a simple timeout wrapper). Can you update your answer to reflect this, because your answer is almost what I am looking for with the parameter expansion.

We have two operations ... 1) run a sample touch and 2) pretty print some output.  Running the touch from within awk is unnecessary overhead, and calling an awk script to just pretty print what we can easily do in bash is overkill (imo).  So, I would opt to do the whole thing in bash.
General approach:

loop through list of paths
if we can successfully touch a file then:
a) rm the file
b) conditionally print the leading '['
c) print the is_available line (preface with ending for previous line)
d) conditionally print trailing ']'
NOTE: ending for previous line takes care of printing the ending , for all but the last line
OPTIONAL: save available paths in array available[] for follow-on bash processing

One bash idea:
$ cat gen.jq
#!/bin/bash

unset available
available=()

count=0
pfx=""                                     # 1st 'is_available' line prefaced with nothing

for path in "$@"
do
    tgt="${path}/.checkalivefile"

    if touch "${tgt}" 2>/dev/null
    then
        rm -f "${tgt}"
        available+=( "${path}" )

        (( count == 0 )) && echo "["       # if this is the 1st time printing an 'is_available'
                                           # line then print the opening '['

        printf "%b  { \"is_available\": %s, \"path\": \"%s\" }" "${pfx}" "${count}" "${path}"

        (( count++ ))

        pfx=",\n"                          # 2nd-nth 'is_available' lines prefaced with ','
                                           # to close out previous line + linefeed
    fi
done

(( count > 0 )) && printf "\n]\n"          # if we printed at least one 'is_available' line
                                           # so close out the last line (\n) and print the
                                           # closing ']'

# typeset -p available                     # uncomment to display array contents

Setup:
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir -p dir1 dir1/subdir1 dir1/subdir2
$ chmod 000 dir1/subdir2

$ tree /tmp
/tmp
├── dir1
│   ├── subdir1
│   └── subdir2  [error opening dir]

Running the script:
$ ./gen.jq /tmp/dir1 /tmp/dir1/subdir1 /tmp/dir1/subdir2 /tmp/dir2 
[
  { "is_available": 0, "path": "/tmp/dir1" },
  { "is_available": 1, "path": "/tmp/dir1/subdir1" }
]

If the typeset -p available line is uncommented the following is also generated:
declare -a available=([0]="/tmp/dir1" [1]="/tmp/dir1/subdir1")

